# Can not retrieve exact id from composite key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I can not retrieve exact id from composite key.
I'm using MySQL and Hibernate.

```
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ProductId.class);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.max("id"));
        criteria.setMaxResults(1);
        Integer max = (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult();

        if (max == null) {
            max = 0;  
//This always giving null.
```

so it does `max =0;`

Before or after inserting there's no issue in database.

But retrieving `id` by using :

```
productId.getId();
```

also giving always zero but in database it is incremented `id` .
Why is it so?

It must not cause it has value:

```
ProductId productId = new ProductId(id, barcode);
        product.setName(name);
        product.setPrice(price);
        product.setId(productId);
```

`id` is ***primary key***, ***auto increment*** and ***unique*** but `barcode` is just ***primary key***.
Those both fields are ***composite keys***.

**Summery :**
When I skip initiating id it gives

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So if it is initialized it can generate id automatically while inserting, even just putting '0'

```
ProductId productId = new ProductId(0, barcode);
```

fulfilling insertion.
But I can not retrieve exact `id`.

I'm saving Product using :

```
String name = jNameTextField.getText();
double price = Double.parseDouble(jPriceTextField.getText());
int barcode = Integer.parseInt(jBarcdTextField.getText());


ProductId productId = new ProductId(0, barcode); // put zero for check  
product.setName(name);
product.setPrice(price);
product.setId(productId);

manager.addProduct(product);
```

Product.java

```
public class Product  implements java.io.Serializable {


     public ProductId id;
     private String name;
     private double price;
     private Stock stock;

public Product() {
    }


    public Product(ProductId id, String name, double price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Product(ProductId id, String name, double price, Stock stock) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
       this.price = price;
       this.stock = stock;
    }
// Getter and Setters
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code for saving a new Product, retrieval after save and the Product class (so we can see the mapping)

Comment: @JohnCamerin Thanks for your time to see. Thank you so much. I've added mentioned code and class.

Comment: I was hoping to see the mapping metadata, but I can make some assumptions based on what is posted. The ProductId class is used like an EmbeddedId. Hibernate does not have table mapping metadata for the ProductId class.

A couple of questions... If the id within ProductId is an autoincrement and unique, why do you have a composite key? Its unnecessary if the id field alone is unique. It would simplify your code to get rid of the ProductId class and just put the barcode and id in the Product class.

Comment: @JohnCamerin ProductID is a composition class generated from Product class while creating POJO . I want barcode also unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still recommend dropping the ProductId class based on the id value within it being unique. 
But, to make the query work with the ProductId class:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
```

Change the criteria to be on the Product class instead of the ProductId class.

I think (but I'm not sure) that the change below is also necessary, pointing Hibernate to the int id field of the ProductId id field.

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.max("id.id"));
```

I also recommend changing the name of one of the two id fields to make the code less confusing.

Comment: Well I tried this that's working but I want to insert data into both tables Product (Parent) and Stock (Child) same time. So now I can insert into Stock but not Product. So can I do what I want?

Comment: That solved my problem. So please would you help what further I get is here [Getting org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.pojo.Product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53912198/getting-org-hibernate-typemismatchexception-provided-id-of-the-wrong-type-for-c)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Looks like you figured out the issue on the other thread. Glad to have helped and good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much each time solving previous issue and waiting new one for there. As I'm developing ahead. Well I'm developing without a plan  that's worst of my project. :-)

Comment: So may I'll keep posting new issues. Thanks a lot for your invaluable time and efforts.